# Complete symmetric distance matrix

Tags: mathematics

Is there an intuitive way to approximate/estimate missing cells in a (symmetric) distance matrix?
In this case, each unknown pair has several "neighbors" for which the distance is known.

Comment: This sounds like the Latin Square technique...